# Sell products in packet form using magento

Tags: magento-1.9, products-management

I am working on one magento site. 
**Question:** I have some products in grams like 0.100 grams, 0.250 grams and some of them are in kgs and I want to sell all these products in packet format like 1 kg = 1 packet also 100 grams = 1 packet, 250 grams = 1 packet.
How I can set or solve this.
**My Magento Version:** 1.9.1.0 
Any suggestion or help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you manage your stock with Magento and need separate SKUs for each package, use a configurable product with associated simple products for each package size.

> A configurable product looks like a single product with drop-down lists of options for each variation. Each option is actually a separate simple product with a unique SKU, which makes it possible to track inventory for each product variation. You could achieve a similar effect by using a simple product with custom options, but without the ability to track inventory for each variation. Products with multiple options are sometimes referred to as composite product.

Read more in the merchant docs: http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#catalog/product-configurable.html%3FTocPath%3DProduct%2520Catalog|Creating%2520Products|_____3

Answer (score 0):

In your product, use Custom Options with a Drop Down menu which lets the customer select the packet size, for example:

```
Title - Price
100g - USD 1 
250g - USD 2.5
1kg  - USD 10
```